# Why is EPE Energy's Revenue different between Nasdaq and Morningstar? understanding financial statements

Tags: financial-statements, nasdaq

Why is EPE Energy's Revenue different between Nasdaq and Morningstar? Below are the two numbers, am I missing something?

says revenue is 1.066 billion for 2017
https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/epe/financials?query=income-statement

says revenue is 1.025 billion for 2017
http://financials.morningstar.com/income-statement/is.html?t=EPE&region=usa

Answer (score 1):

Many providers will "normalize" financial statements so that comparing between companies is more consistent (meaning the same activities are bucketed consistently).

Looking at the [raw financial statements](http://quote.morningstar.com/stock-filing/Annual-Report/2017/12/31/t.aspx?t=:EPE&ft=10-K&d=1eb5b0df6fe341a52e6f2cd365e216bf), it appears that Nasdaq is excluding the $41M gain in "Financial derivatives" from "revenue" and including it as a contra-expense in "cost of revenue". This is reasonable since the derivative income/loss is not impacted by operations but a result of hedging activities to reduce commodity price risk.